# Upload file type detection in CodeIgniter 2.1.4

Tags: codeigniter, upload, mime

It gives an error

```
"Error: The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed."
```

even the extension is specified in allowed types.

Comment: Can you put your some part of code.

Comment: Got the answer. Get mime type by following code

    echo $this->upload->file_type ;

and use it after 

    $this->upload->do_upload();

Add that mime type in the file /application/config/mimes.php for corresponding file type extension.

Also if a file extension is not available in mimes.php, you can add your own in the mimes array e.g.

    'pptx' => array('application/powerpoint')

where 'application/powerpoint' is the mime type.

Comment: what are the types you are allowing?

Comment: If you want to upload all types of file, you have to add $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; like jpg,png,pdf,doc,etc...

Answer (score 1):

In CI, You have to set allowed files in `config` before doing upload. [Source](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

If you upload other than above gif, jpg and png , you will get error message.

Answer (score 1):

You simply needed to perform few things:

1. Set *allowed types* of the file type you are going to upload:

   `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';`
2. Dump the type of file and get the exact filetype then include that mime type in `mimes.php`